# Show that a A is Borel if and only if T(A) is Borel, where T is a rotation.

Tags: measure-theory

Let T be a rotation about the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Show that a subset A of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is Borel if and only if T(A) is Borel.

My try:

First show that if A is Borel, then T(A) is Borel.

For that, let $\mathfrak{A} := \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: T(A) \textrm{ is Borel }\}$. This is a $\sigma$-algebra.

$\emptyset \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2} \in \mathfrak{A}$ and if

$A \in \mathfrak{A} $, $T(A)$ is Borel and so is also $T(A)^{C}$ = $T(A^{C})$ so $A^{C} \in \mathfrak{A}$.

Finally,

If $\cup_{i} T(A_{i})$ is a sequence of sets in $\mathfrak{A}$ then it is a union of borel sets and thus borel, since $\cup_{i} T(A_{i}) = T (\cup_{i} A_{i})$, then $\cup_{i} A_{i} \in \mathfrak{A}$

Since $\mathfrak{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and T is continuous, $\mathfrak{A}$ contains all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and so $\mathfrak{A}$ contains the Borel sigma algebra $\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R^{2}})}$.

So if A is Borel, then also $T(A)$ is Borel since $\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R^{2}})} \subset \mathfrak{A}$.

Other direction:

Assume $T(A)$ is Borel, by the same argument as above, we can construct a sigma-algebra $S := \{ B \in \mathfrak{A}: T^{-1}(B) \textrm{ is Borel} \}$ containing all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and since $T^{-1}(B) = T^{-1}T(A) =A$ we are done.

There are probably simple ways of showing this, however, what is your thoughts about this and which methods are better?

Comment: I posted that one yesterday to use it for this question. That one is only concerning the question whether the collection of subsets of A such that T(A) is borel is a sigma-algebra and this one aims to prove that A is Borel if and only if T(A) is Borel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to prove that $ T: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2} $ is a homeomorphism, because we can then exploit the fact that the pre-image of a Borel set under a continuous mapping is a Borel set (this is pretty much what you have done above). If $ T[A] $ is Borel, then $ A = {T^{-1}}[T[A]] $ is Borel. If $ A $ is Borel, then $ T[A] $ is Borel, as $ T $ is the inverse mapping of $ T^{-1} $.

Comment: Ok, thanks, however is my attempt false or incomplete or is it also correct?

Comment: The proof that $ {\frak{A}} $ is a $ \sigma $-algebra is fine, as you have verified that all the axioms of a $ \sigma $-algebra hold. To prove that $ {\frak{A}} $ contains the open subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^{2} $, you need to say: If $ A $ is open, then $ T[A] $ is open (hence Borel) because $ T $ is an open mapping (which is true of a homeomorphism).

Comment: Ok, I was a bit unclear but that was what I meant with 

"
Since $\mathfrak{A}$ is a σ-algebra and T is continuous, $\mathfrak{A}$ contains all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and so $\mathfrak{A}$ contains the Borel sigma algebra $\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R}^{2})}$.
"
If A is open then T(A) is open by continuity and both A and T(A) are Borel